# Is this test robust? Can I use DispatchQueue.main.async() in a unit test?

Tags: swift

Simplifying a bit the code structure, I have a `UIViewController` with `viewDidLoad()` that calls a method that uses `DispatchQueue.main.async()` to wait for the main thread to execute the code.

```
viewDidLoad() {
   method()
}

method() {
   ...
   DispatchQueue.main.async() {
      ...some code...
   }
}
```

My test also need to wait for the main thread before to call XCTAssertEqual.

```
func testSuccessRequest() {
        let exp = expectation(description: "labelText")
        let vc = ViewController.init()
        vc.request = SuccessRequest.init()
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()

        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            XCTAssertEqual(vc.label.text, "success")
            exp.fulfill()
        }

        waitForExpectations(timeout: 40, handler: nil)
}
```

Is this test robust? Or could I have situations in which the assert code is called before the async?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since method() is async so while testing if you call

```
DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            XCTAssertEqual(vc.label.text, "success")
            exp.fulfill()
        }
```

right after vc.loadViewIfNeeded() you are not guaranteed that test case expectation will get full fill before async method() calls gets completed. 
Since both calls - method() & above - are async.

But what you can do is - ful fill test case expectation after some time like below:

```
   dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            XCTAssertEqual(vc.label.text, "success")
            [expectation fulfill];
            });

waitForExpectations(timeout: 40, handler: nil)
```

This is the one way you can test async method which is uses GCD. Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
 While above strategy can make you wait for 2s. There is better method in this scenario we can implement.

We can take help of XCTKVOExpectation and XCTWaiter class available in XCTest framework. Here is the brief descriptions about them:

- **XCTKVOExpectation** 
  Cretes an expectation which is full filled by "keyPath" of an observed 
  object
- **XCTWaiter**
  Provides more descriptive return value when expectation timeout compare to normal *waitForExpectations(timeout:, handler:)* which simply throws error.

Now your test case will look like.

```
   func testSuccessRequest() {            
        let promise = XCTKVOExpectation(keyPath: "text", object: vc.label,
                                              expectedValue: "success")
        let vc = ViewController.init()
        vc.request = SuccessRequest.init()
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
        let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [promise], timeout: 40)
        XCTAssertTrue(result == .completed)
    }
```

Here, a KVO exp. is created on "text" properties of label and then view is loaded with async call and then test case wait for some time before time out. Then you can assert the return value from XCTWaiter.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi, so you are using a delay of 2 seconds, right? But isn't that just a workaround? I would rather not have to slow down my tests by just setting a random delay value.

Comment: Thanks. your solution works, and it seems to me that I could use it regularly when I'm dealing with asynchronous threads. I was wondering though: how common is this problem? It seems that you had to think a little about it. But isn't very common that UILabel are updated asynchronously? In other words: how common is the solution you gave me?

Comment: This is the common problem with GCD function or KVO where it doesn't return callback. These are the scenario it is useful. I really had to improve on my prev. solution where we have deliberate delay.